# Как бы я мог обрезать строку с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

я пытался извлечь слово VISA из данной строки "Wallet Funding : VISA(4224xxxxxxxx8896)", но у меня не получается достать это слово. Иногда вместо VISA появляется другая платёжная система.

Comment: По идее, у вас должен быть набор входных строк. По ним можно составить шаблон регулярки. А по одной строке сложно судить, как и что извлекать.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String str = "Wallet Funding : VISA(4224xxxxxxxx8896)";
    String word = "VISA";
    int indexFrom = str.indexOf(word);
    int indexTo = indexFrom + word.length();
    String substring = str.substring(indexFrom, indexTo);
```

Только не понятно, зачем вытягивать слово, которое уже известно. Может я не правильно понял вопрос? Конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста

И с помощью регулярных выражений проверяется соответствует ли строка заданному шаблону, так что обрезать строку с помощью регулярок - это некорректный либо неточный вопрос.

Comment: Вы точно не поняли вопрос: надо найти слово, которое неизвестно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ, думаю что я не правильно задал вопрос, на месте слова VISA иногда может быть MASTER CARD(MC) или MAESTRO и.т.д. В конечном я извлёк данное слово немного другим способом.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы найти слово VISA в данной строке, можно найти совпадение двоеточия с возможными пробелами после и 1 и более букв из таблицы ASCII.

Используйте

```
String s = "Wallet Funding : VISA(4224xxxxxxxx8896)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\\s*([A-Z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => VISA
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/s1qulH) и его схему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Ww1Dhs/1).

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, регуляка `(?<=\:\s)(.*?)(?=\()`

```
public void found() {
    String line = "Wallet Funding : VISA(4224xxxxxxxx8896)";
    String pattern = "(?<=\\:\\s)(.*?)(?=\\()";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение! Оно полезно для меня.